# how to get this response in python, like in bash?

Tags: python, bash, request

how to do transfer this bash curl in python code.

piece of code what i want remake in python:

`response=$(curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" "https://api.selvpc.ru/identity/v3/auth/tokens" -d " { \"auth\": { \"identity\": { \"methods\": [\"password\"], \"password\": { \"user\": { \"name\": \"$USER_NAME\",  \"domain\": { \"name\": \"$ID_SELECTEL\" }, \"password\": \"$PASSWORD\" } } }, \"scope\": { \"project\": { \"name\": \"$PROJECT_NAME\", \"domain\": { \"name\": \"$ID_SELECTEL\" } } } } }")`

what i did:

```
HEADERS = { \
    "Content-type": "application/json"}

PARAMETRES={\
        "auth":{\
            "identity":{\
                "methods":["password"], \
                "password":{\
                    "user":{\
                        "name" : USER_NAME, \
                        "domain" : {\
                            "name":ID_SELECTEL
                        }, \
                        "password":PASSWORD
                    }
                }
            },\

            "scope":{\
                "project":{\
                    "name":PROJECT_NAME, \
                    "domain":{\
                        "name":ID_SELECTEL \
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
response = requests.get(DATA_URL, params=PARAMETRES, headers=HEADERS)
print(response)
```

output:
`<Response [401]>`

I think I might have lost some dictionaries and this is making an error.

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: Please don't cram your shell code all onto 1 line and then ask people to read/understand it. Your python code is well-formatted, why not do the same with your shell code? Use sensible, legible newlines and indenting in your code to make it as easy for us to understand as possible so more people will be willing to help you. Not my downvote by the way.

Comment: curl sends the data in a POST request, not GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is most likely related to the POST request. The original bash script uses `curl -d`, which indicates a POST request, not a GET.

In addition, you pass your parameters as params, which adds them to the URL. Instead, you should pass them in the request body using the `json` or `data` keyword (depends on what type the server expects - JSON or regular data).

Your rewritten code may look like this:

```
import requests
import json
HEADERS = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

PARAMETERS = {
    "auth": {
        "identity": {
            "methods": ["password"],
            "password": {
                "user": {
                    "name" : USER_NAME,
                        "domain" : {
                        "name": ID_SELECTEL
                    },
                    "password": PASSWORD
                }
            }
        },
        "scope": {
            "project": {
                "name": PROJECT_NAME,
                "domain": {
                    "name": ID_SELECTEL
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

response = requests.post('https://api.selvpc.ru/identity/v3/auth/tokens', 
                         headers=HEADERS, 
                         data=json.dumps(PARAMETERS))
print(response)
```

Note that the URL for the request is now included in the `requests.post` parameters, and not as a `DATA_URL` variable. The parameters encoded in JSON are transmitted using the `data` keyword.

When working with the API, it is common practice to process response status codes. If you receive a 401, it indicates an authentication problem - your username or password may be incorrect, or the server may require additional authentication that you have not provided.

Answer (score 0):

cURL is making an HTTP POST request, however, you are making a GET request on Python.

Just edit the requests.get to `requests.post(DATA_URL, json=PARAMETERS, headers=HEADERS)`